# getElementById("demoname").value return undefine

Tags: javascript

My `JS` code return `undefined`. The tag is goog, but value is missing. why?

```
<body>
    <p id = "demo">fffffffff</p>
    <button onclick = "fun()">click</button>

    <script type="text/javascript" defer = "defer">
        function fun(){
        alert(document.getElementById("demo").value);
    }   
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`p` tag doesn't have a `value`. It have `textContent`. Only `input` elements have `value` attribute

```html
<body>
<p id = "demo">fffffffff</p>
<button onclick = "fun()">click</button>
<script type="text/javascript" defer = "defer">
    function fun(){
    alert(document.getElementById("demo").textContent);
}   
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: what's the difference between textContent and innerHTML though?

Comment: _"Only `input` elements have `value` attribute"_ - or `<button>`, `<li>`, `<progress>`, `<object>`, `<meter>`

Comment: @Andreas Yeah. Button is again `input`. Thanks for that other elements list though.

Answer (score 1):

YOu need to alert the `innerHTML`, not the `value`

```html
<body>
<p id = "demo">fffffffff</p>
<button onclick = "fun()">click</button>
<script type="text/javascript" defer = "defer">
    function fun(){
    alert(document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML);
}   
</script>
</body>`
```

Answer (score 1):

`<p>` tag is not having `value`. You can choose to use `textContent`, `innerHTML` or `innerText`. All of these has benefits and limitations.

If you only want text written in `<p>` then you should use `textContent`

> textContent is not supported in IE8 or earlier

**Example**

```
<p id=“demo”><ul><li>mytext</li></ul></p>
var x=document.getElementById(“demo”);

var output = x.textContent;
```

**Output**

mytext

If you want text with Html (like `UL`, `LI` ) from `<p>` then you should use `innerHTML`

```
var output = x.innerHTML;
```

**Output**

- mytext

> innerHTML is supported by all browsers

You can also use `innerText`.

> innerText will not include text that is hidden by CSS, but textContent will

So choose as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `.innerHTML` property instead.

```
alert(document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML);
```